# newman: exportGlobals option within newman.run does not take the path specified

Tags: postman, newman

I am trying to use this within my test1.js:

```
const newman = require('newman'); // require newman in your project

// call newman.run to pass `options` object and wait for callback
newman.run({
  collection: require('./postman/poc_collection.json')
  environment: require('./postman/poc_env.json'),
  exportGlobals: require('./postman/poc_globals.json'),
  reporters: 'cli'
}, function (err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  console.log('collection run complete!');
});
```

When the run completes, the file **newman-globals-2019-01-11-14-39-00-154-0.json** gets generated instead of using the **poc_globals.json** file specified above.

The --export-globals option within the newman command line works fine.

What I am missing?

Thanks,
Ramya

Comment: Where are you getting that property name from?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the require() while setting the path to the globals file. Try:

```
exportGlobals: './postman/poc_globals.json',
```

However, you need to use it, if you want your script to be loading variables from the globals file.

```
globals: require('./postman/poc_globals.json'),
```